# Redirect pagination url in htaccess [WordPress]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In my new WordPress theme, I changed the pagination url from `page/[number]/` to `posts/page/[number]/`

I am using following htaccess code in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /posts/page/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and so on. But it is not working.

I am expecting the following redirection:

`page/2/` --> `posts/page/2/`

`page/3/` --> `posts/page/3/`

`page/4/` --> `posts/page/4/`

But it is not redirecting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use an .htaccess?
WordPress already offers a feature to create custom rules on your permalinks.

Just go to your backoffice -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Custom Structure and enter the structure you want to use.

Comment: Because these pages are still indexed on google and I want to redirect it properly for those landing from google to my site.